# Android custom style in dialog

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a dialog with a custom theme following this tutorial:
http://androblip.huiges.nl/2010/05/09/theme-android-dialog/

I created a custom theme:

values/styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

I'm trying to create a dialog with this theme in MainActivity.java:

```
 final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context, android.R.style.AppTheme);
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'AppTheme'

I also tried reading the documentation on styles and themes (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html), but I couldn't find anything.

I also tried cleaning the project, but it still can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.AppTheme);`

Comment: wow I must be blind lol, I spent so long trying to figure this out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For android default style you have to use

android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Dialog
for example

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Dialog);
```

For your custom style you have to use
R.style.your_style

for example

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.AppTheme);
```